# Correcting a Slogan

Tags: singular-vs-plural, headlinese

I'd like someone to share their inputs on this. An educational institute I am associated with has this motto: 'Hard work and discipline are our tradition'.

I am not quite satisfied with that... I am not sure if I should let it be as it is, or change it the following:
(A) Hard work and discipline is our tradition.
(B) Hard work and discipline are our traditions.

**Specific Need** I need to mention that we may be able to change a letter here and there or maybe a word (like converting is to are) but we won't be able to rework the entire slogan. What I basically should I have asked before is:
Is "Hard work and discipline are our tradition" correct in itself?
Should 'hard work and discipline' be considered as a single noun phrase or two different nouns here?

Comment: I, too, prefer "Hard work and discipline is our tradition." Being a little bold, I might even say that "Hard work and discipline is our traditions," is preferred. -- The pattern "X [is|are] Y" doesn't force the plurality agreement of X and Y; however, the choice of [is|are] must conform to the plurality of X.

Comment: The singularity or plurality of 'hard work and discipline' would be the topic of another thread altogether! I consider this as a singular noun phrase and not as two segregate nouns. Hence, I prefer 'Hard work and discipline is our tradition' as well. In any case, what the school uses as the current motto is incorrect.

Comment: @DamkerngT. "Hard work and discipline is our traditions" is ungrammatical.

Comment: Whether "hard word and discipline" is one or two things is the key. If you viewed it (them?) as one thing, then it would be singular. On the other hand, if you viewed them as two separate things, then saying "Hard work and discipline are ..." is fine.

Comment: I concur with snailplane. "Hard work and discipline is our traditions" is completely ungrammatical from any point of view.

Comment: @snailplane Hmm... This is getting interesting. Is a sentence such as "It is our traditions" (whatever this *it* refers to) ungrammatical?

Comment: Why would we say that vis-a-vis 'It is our tradition'? When we say "our" tradition, it means everything that is a part of our tradition. Why do we need to use that as plural?

Comment: If so much discussion arises on this slogan, a re-work could remove the nagging ambiguities. Perhaps "A tradition of hard work and discipline", which very clearly forces the idea that [hard work and discipline] is a combined and singular concept.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes.  It _(singular)_ is our traditions _(plural)_ is ungrammatical. It is part of our traditions, or it is one of our traditions would work in those situations.

Comment: I realize this is not what you were asking, but it strikes me that any hint of _traditional discipline_ is going to conjure up images of [corporal punishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporal_punishment).

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung You are right Tyler. I am going to post this entire conversation to the principal of our institution and put my point across.

Comment: I see other problems with this slogan. [Join me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners) if you wish to discuss.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung That's not necessarily a problem. He is not an American. "Traditional discipline" doesn't necessarily mean the same in his culture. That aside, quite frankly, the slogan sounds quite silly, something a school kid would write. "Hard work and discipline is/are our tradition." Oh really? I have never come across any institute or business that claims "Laziness and indiscipline is our tradition." so their Captain Obvious 'motto' doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: @Happy I agree with you in principle. The slogan is quite childish. I would never have come up with something like that. I wanted to get some feedback on the current slogan as it is, and I think I am getting more than I asked for. Also, let me ask you - what has being American or not got to do with it?

Comment: @NeilD'Silva Pretty simple. The term "traditional discipline" is associated with corporal punishment *in US (and maybe a bunch of other countries)*, but that's hardly a universal statement. In fact, in my place, "traditional discipline" itself is a rather unknown term, and nobody uses it commonly, leave aside having any meaning attached to it. I only wanted to point out that "traditional discipline has unintended meanings in US" doesn't necessarily mean it will be a problem everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Both are okay. I see them this way -

> [Hard work and discipline] is our tradition. 
>   [Hard work] and [discipline] are our traditions.

*Hard work* may not take a hyphen as it's used as a noun and not a compound adjective.

Comment: Hard-work isn't an adjective here. It is a noun.

Comment: @NeilD'Silva Oh, I really missed it. In that case, it won't take hyphen I guess.

Comment: Yes, that's decided. There will be no hyphen. If we refer to its adjectival form as you previously indicated, it would have a hyphen though, and that would be 'hard-working'.